# Java Regex to Match URL

Tags: java, regex

I need to create Regexes to match URLs of the following forms

```
/collected/{deliveryId}/deliverer/{userId}
/customer/{userId}/status/active
/users/{userId}/role
```

Where delivery-id and user-id are UUIDs in the form of: `124r23452-124234234-123123423534` and the other string parts are constant.

For the first one I tried something like this but didnt work:

```
    String urlRegex = "[a-zA-Z-]*/collected/deliverer/(?=\\S*[-])([a-zA-Z-]+)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern : `\/collected\/\w{0,9}\/deliverer\/\w{0,}` and use https://regex101.com/ web site. This [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) page, gives also some good details on regex.

[image]